# How can I assign more than 2 phone numbers to a contact on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, contacts

A large proportion of contacts I have gained over the years have more than two current numbers.

Examples include: home, work, mobile; home, NZ work no., US work  no., Spanish work no; etc

I have only worked out how to add two numbers to particular contact; after that, when you click add there is no other options.

This is *crazy*, this is 2010, I must be doing something wrong, **can you help me out?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can add as many phone numbers as I want on the iPhone. When you're in edit mode in the contact, there's always a blank line under current phone numbers where you can start typing a new one.

If you click on the label of the number, you can select a label (work, home) and even a custom label if you scroll to the bottom of the label selection list.

Comment: So I haven't actually owned an iphone in about 6months but a friend recently got one and had this problem, and I remember being confused about it when I owned one. Has it always been like this, or are we just unimaginably thick?

Comment: @SCdF - I think it has always been like this but I'm not sure either. My first iPhone was 3GS with iPhone OS 3.

Comment: @JacobGorban My iPhone 4S has the entry "Add Custom Label" at the bottom of the label-picker screen, below all of my existing custom labels.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter a phone number for the contact, immediately below that number should appear a new place to enter another phone number. You can change the type of phone like work, home, iPhone, blackberry, etc.